# Uses a different AUTH cakephp

Tags: authentication, cakephp, controller

I have this auth in me appController

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' > [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Centros',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);
```

But i want use other auth in other login, i tried this but always return false but idk why.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' > [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel'=>'Personas',
                'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Usuarios',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Personas',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);
```

In the latter case, if I change personas for user it works but not with personas.

Comment: What does "not work" mean here? What behaviour do you see, and how does it differ from what you're expecting?

Comment: not work when i put the userModel personas always return false when i tried to login.

Comment: Are the fields called `username` and `password` in the `personas` table? Is there a record there? Is the password for it hashed correctly?